# In a for loop, how do I assign a table of values to a new variable for every iteration?

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

I am trying to create a divided differences table for a set of data of depth n, specified by the user. I am not sure how to create and assign a new variable name for each iteration of the for loop. Below is the code that I currently have written.

My current plan is to have an initial condition "d0table" and have further divided difference tables called "d1table", "d2table", and so on.

```
d0table = {53.32, 
  51.7, 56.05, 57.71, 62.05, 78.94, 74.74, 76.24, 68.29, 85.24}; (*initial condition*)
n = 1; (*depth of table*)

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
 ToExpression["d" <> ToString[i] <> "table"] = 
  Table[(ToExpression["d" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "table"][[k + 1]] - 
    ToExpression["d" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "table"][[k]])/(
   t[[k + i]] - t[[k]]), {k, 1, 
    Length[ToExpression["d" <> ToString[i - 1] <> "table"] - 1]}]
 ]
```

Upon running the code, I find that the tag "ToExpression" in "ToExpression[d1table]" is Protected. Is there any way to create a different variable name for each iteration of the for loop?

In the end, d1table should be an input like

```
d1table = 
 Table[(d0table[[k + 1]] - d0table[[k]])/(
  t[[k + 1]] - t[[k]]), {i, 1, 9}]
```

and output to

```
{-1.62, 4.35, 1.66, 4.34, 16.89, -4.2, 1.5, -7.95, 16.95}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Could you manually calculate and add to your post what `d1table` should look like?

Comment: This is a terrible abuse of `ToExpression`. You can use indexed variables like `dtable[i]` and `dtable[i-1]` etc. for assignments.

Comment: @Roman, I can't believe I didn't think of this. Didn't realize you could specify parts for indexed variables like that - Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, `ToExpression` was the wrong command to use. Assigning indexed variables and asking Mathematica to find the specific parts works like a charm. The code with the correct output is below.

```
dtable[0] = {53.32, 51.7, 56.05, 57.71, 62.05, 78.94, 74.74, 76.24, 
   68.29, 85.24};(*initial condition*)
n = 1;(*depth of table*)
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
 dtable[i] = 
  Table[(dtable[i - 1][[k + 1]] - dtable[i - 1][[k]])/(t[[k + i]] - 
      t[[k]]), {k, 1, Length[dtable[i - 1]] - 1}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `NestList`:

```
NestList[Differences, d0table, 3]

{{53.32, 51.7, 56.05, 57.71, 62.05, 78.94, 74.74, 76.24, 68.29, 
  85.24}, {-1.62, 4.35, 1.66, 4.34, 16.89, -4.2, 1.5, -7.95, 
  16.95}, {5.97, -2.69, 2.68, 12.55, -21.09, 5.7, -9.45, 
  24.9}, {-8.66, 5.37, 9.87, -33.64, 26.79, -15.15, 34.35}}
```